# How to enable a backspace work inside a form textbox?

Tags: javascript

I'm using a form where in a text box is bound to a variable object by its path. I also have a button to fetch few records based on the input given in this text box. When I enter something for the first time and hit the button, it fetches the records. But again if I try to hit backspace or delete buttons inside the text box, it takes me to the previous page instead of simply deleting the text inside. Is there a way out? I tried with events like preventDefault() using keyCode restrictions, but in vain. Please help.

PS: This text box has regex validations and also has logic to pre-populate.

Comment: We're not mind readers. Post your code please.

Comment: Backspace button when a page self (and not a specific input field) has the focus indeeds triggers a "previous page"... never heard of it with `del` though. From where I see it your problem may be related to this "focus" thing, but hard to tell without seeing any code.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Bartdude. The cursor focus is inside the text box. However, Delete button isn't working at all inside the text box.

Comment: Please post a jsFiddle with that issue showing. It would also be of help to know if that happens on a specific browser only or on all of them. There must be something else specifically blocking these keys cause I never saw this problem.

Answer (score 0):

when records are fetched, you lose the focus on your text box. When you press the Backspace key once more, the browser takes you to the previous page (as most browers do). Set the focus back on your element after you fetch the records or change you code so the records fetching will not change the focused element.

See : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.focus

Comment: Thanks for the response @sodawillow. But the issue is actually when the cursor focus is inside the text box. Ideally, backspace button should delete the text that's before the blinking cursor. But, as mentioned earlier, it renders the application to its previous page.

Comment: Could you please post some code then ? Are you using a real input field in an HTML form ? I made a quick test and in a focused input field the general behavior should be blocked.